# Setting up azureSubscriptionEndpoint

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

So I'm trying to setup a task that just applies manifests based on the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/kubernetes?view=azure-devops#commands).

This is what I have:

```
variables:
  azureSubscriptionEndpoint: '<UID>'
  # azureSubscriptionEndpoint: 'Pay-As-You-Go'
  # azureSubscriptionEndpoint: 'Pay-As-You-Go (<UID>)'
  azureResourceGroup: `test-app`
  kubernetesCluster: `testappaks`

stages:
- stage: Manifests
  displayName: Apply Manifests
  dependsOn: Changes
  condition: eq(dependencies.Changes.outputs['Myvariable.Manifests'], 'true') 
  jobs:
  - job: Ingress
    displayName: Apply Ingress Manifest
    pool :
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Kubernetes@1
      displayName: kubectl apply using arguments
      inputs:
        connectionType: Azure Resource Manager
        azureSubscriptionEndpoint: $(azureSubscriptionEndpoint)
        azureResourceGroup: $(azureResourceGroup)
        kubernetesCluster: $(kubernetesCluster)
        command: apply
        arguments: -f manifests/azure-ingress.yaml
```

When it triggers the pipeline, I get this error:

[image]

Clicking on "Authorize resources" just says:

[image]

- I've gone to "Project Settings" > "Service Connections*", where I
  don't see `azureSubscriptionEndpoint`
- I've tried adding "New service connection" with Azure Classic, Azure Resource Manager, and calling it `azureSubscriptionEndpoint` which does not resolve the issue
- I've tried adding the subscription string which does not resolve the issue

Basically wondering what I need to do to resolve this.

Comment: How did you create service connection? Have you authorized the service?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I created the service connection at "Project Settings" > "Service Connection" > "New Service Connection" > Tried Azure Classic and Azure Resource Manager. I selected my Subscription, resource group and granted permissions to all pipelines per the sidebar.

Comment: Could you try Manual subscription pipeline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-azure-resource-manager?

Comment: I tried again "Project Settings" > "Service Connection" > "New Service Connection" > "Azure Resource Manager" > "Service Principals Automatic". This time I did just call it by the subscription `<UID>` string. Then when I clicked "Authorize resources" it said it was successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was along the right path, but found I had to name the new service connection after the subscription ID number. At least, that is the only time it works--it does not with any other name.

So the steps for me were:

1. "Project Settings"
2. "Service connections"
3. "New service connection"
4. "Azure Resource Manager"
5. "Service principal (automatic)"
6. Then these were the parameters I used for setting up the new service connection:

   - Scope Level: Subscription
   - Subscription: picked my subscription ("Pay-As-You-Go ()")
   - Resource group: AKS resource group, not the one it automatically creates
   - Service connection name:
   - Grant access permission to all pipelines: checked
7. Save

After that the `azure-pipelines.yml` ran that task fine and subsequent `Kubernetes@1` tasks using the same variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might just be missing a concept. `$(azureSubscriptionEndpoint)` is a variable that you need to define in your yaml pipeline definition.

```
variables:
    azureSubscriptionEndpoint: Contoso
    azureContainerRegistry: contoso.azurecr.io
    azureResourceGroup: Contoso
    kubernetesCluster: Contoso

steps:
- task: Kubernetes@1
  displayName: kubectl apply
  inputs:
    connectionType: Azure Resource Manager
    azureSubscriptionEndpoint: $(azureSubscriptionEndpoint)
    azureResourceGroup: $(azureResourceGroup)
    kubernetesCluster: $(kubernetesCluster)
```

So in the above example its expected that you have Service Connection named `Contoso`.

When the pipleline runs it will resolve `azureSubscriptionEndpoint` based on the value you set for the variable `$(azureSubscriptionEndpoint)`. You want to define that service connection [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-kuber).

Comment: No, I get that. "I've tried adding the subscription string which does not resolve the issue." I still get the same errors. There is just something more that needs to be done per the warning messages I posted. That is what I'm having difficulty figuring out.